# Setting nginx as a reverse proxy help

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm a bit new to reversing caching proxy.. Just wanting to setup a on my ssl requests, The secure.mydomain mainly deliverys txt and gz static small (less than 200k) files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My current nginx.conf:
http://pastebin.com/xcS6bH3B

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on what you are asking for, but I think these links might point you in the correct direction:

Example of reverse proxy with cache: http://wiki.nginx.org/ReverseProxyCachingExample

Documentation for those options: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache